# Tezos-node unable to validate block

Tags: node, error, archive-node

Syncing an archive-mode node, was able to successfully sync up to block 867,487 (March 16, 2020) but now seem to be stuck validating 867,488. The only information in the logs is:

```
validator.peer: Worker crashed [validator-peer_172901]:
validator.peer: (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds")
Validation of block BLQbhHFA6nUCoMz5nzKdw29RCHxXUaQKrD2bwerDbFyLYBDsp9p failed
```

This block is valid and present on the main chain. The node is running off the latest `tezos/tezos:mainnet` docker image.

Has anyone run into this kind of issue before? Seems like maybe some local state corruption. Are there things that can be done to identify or reset whichever state is having issues?

Comment: Run out of disk space?

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of this error is this context … It could be related to a corrupted operation received for this block. Do you have the full error stack (especially when this error pops for the first time)?

To solve your problem, you can run `tezos-admin-client list rejected blocks`. This command should output both the error and the related block hash (it should be `BLQbhHFA6nUCoMz5nzKdw29RCHxXUaQKrD2bwerDbFyLYBDsp9p` in your case).

Then, run `tezos-admin-client unmark invalid <the_block_hash>` to restart the validation process of this block.